# Creating xsd document from file download

Tags: python, amazon-s3, xsd, lxml

I am trying to load an xsd document that is stored on s3. It gives me the following err

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xsd_url = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml'
>>> node=etree.fromstring(requests.get(xsd_url).text)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3092, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:70473)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1823, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106272)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

I verified that the file is in fact correct and it loads locally. How would I load it from s3 though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) which is type `bytes`

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xsd_url = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml'
>>> node = etree.fromstring(requests.get(xsd_url).content))
```

The problem is that your xml file specifies an encoding, and therefore it is the xml parser's job to decode this encoding. But your code uses `.text`, which asks `requests` to decode the encoding.

This does the right thing, but the XML parser does not like being given an already-decoded thing, and then being told how to decode it, so throws the exception you see. The fix? Don't have `requests` decode it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `urllib2` and try doing something like this:

```
    xsd_url = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml'
    xsd_contents = urllib2.urlopen(xsd_url).read()
    xmlschema_doc = etree.fromstring(xsd_contents)
```

Comment: _"Don't use it"_ is not usually the right answer to _"this library isn't working properly"_. It's more likely _"Check you're using it correctly"_